# Django rest framework filter with or condition

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am using Django Rest Framework Filter to access my data. I need to get data that answers one of two conditions. Example:

```
Mywebsite/api/animal/?name=lion||name=frog
```

The `||` is not working. Does anyone know how I can do this filter?

Comment: Post your error logs.

Comment: ן don't have error log.. It just don't repeat any results. It not suppose to return results because it not the right way to do that. My question it what's the write way to do this request

Comment: Is it this one you are using: [DRF Filters](https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters)? If so, please post the FilterSet you defined.

Answer (score 8):

I realize this maybe a little old but i solved it like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q


class FooViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Foo.objects.all()
    status = self.request.query_params.get('status', None)

    def get_queryset(self):
        if status is not None:
            status = status.split('|')
            query = Q()
            for x in status:
                q = Q(status=x)
                query |= q
            queryset = queryset.filter(query)
        return queryset
```

My url then looks like this:

```
example.com/api/foo/?status=test1|test2|test3
```

and filters like this

```
Foo.objects.filter(Q(status=test1)|Q(status=test2)|Q(status=test3))
```

Comment: are you using `self` in class?